# Imagine a single round round-robin chess tournament of 16 players. What is the probability that any two players meet each other within first 3 rounds?

Tags: probability, recreational-mathematics, problem-solving

I am thinking of doing something like this:

P(Player A and Player B meet in the first round) + P(Player A and Player B don't meet in the first round)*P(Player A and Player B meet in the second round) + P(Player A and Player B don't meet in first round)*P(Player A and Player B don't meet in the second round)*P(Player A and Player B meet in the third round)?

Am I thinking it correctly? Would like to hear what other think?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong... but a round-robin style tournament is one where every person eventually plays against every other person eventually, yes?  There is no player elimination that occurs.  When you say "round" do we have as many possible games occurring at once as possible and all of these games together constitute a round?  Multiple tables occurring in a grand hall?  Or do we have a single game occurring at a time, like on a central stage where everybody watches?

Comment: Assuming multiple games occurring simultaneously, you should be able to convince yourself that there will be $15$ rounds altogether and $A$ and $B$ are equally likely to meet in any particular round compared to any other particular round and they meet only once.  The probability they meet within the first three rounds is then $\frac{3}{15}$

Comment: See an example tournament schedule for such a scenario [here](https://www.printyourbrackets.com/16teamroundrobin.html).

Comment: Yes, every player will play against every other player and there are no eliminations. A round consists of 8 pairings (since there are 16 players) and you can think of multiple tables occurring in a grand hall.

Comment: Can you please elaborate how you arrived at 3/15 a bit more?

Comment: There are $15$ equally likely rounds in which they meet, them meeting in one round means they can not meet in any other so they are disjoint events, there are three "good" outcomes we hope for... so the total number of good outcomes divided by the total number of outcomes, $\frac{3}{15}$, is our probability.

Comment: Yes, you could have written this as $\frac{1}{15}+\frac{14}{15}\cdot\frac{1}{14}+\frac{14}{15}\cdot\frac{13}{14}\cdot\frac{1}{13}$ if you really insisted, it is not wrong to do so, but it is far easier to write it as $\frac{1}{15}+\frac{1}{15}+\frac{1}{15}$ or even more directly as $\frac{3}{15}$.  The point is to recognize that meeting in round $i$ is equal to $\frac{1}{15}$ for every $i$.

Comment: Thank you so much JMoravitz, really appreciate it :)